# Работа с несколькими базами данных одновременно

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, entity-framework

Создаю приложение калькулятор, в котором пользователь создает **формулу** расчета и сохраняется в **Базе Данных** SQL Server, нужно реализовать **подключение к БД** с исходными данными, откуда берется таблица, столбец которой соотносится с переменной в формуле. Отсюда выходит что мне надо работать с двумя таблица одновременно. 
Возможна ли работа с двумя БД одновременно, т.к. насколько я понял подключение идет через connectionString ,который только один, где можно указать только одно подключение, как реализовать, возможно ли это c Entity Framework или делать на чистом С#?

Comment: А таблицы у вас в одной бд. или в разных?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы не правы, можно использовать не одну ConnectionString, это выглядит примерно вот так:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FirstDb" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\FirstDb.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
    <add name="SecondDb" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SecondDb.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Ну и контекст нужен сразу для двух БД одновременно.